# How to update JavaFX LineChart data

Tags: java, javafx-2

I using a JavaFX LineChart to display server performance, i want the graph to be updated dynamically with the data fetch from the servers.

How can i add new data one the graph and keep always the same time range in graph (in my case the time is X axis), and Y axis is number of request per second.

edit: I using latest JavaFX JDK7u6

Comment: If you want to retain all data in your series, you can achieve the same result without removing any points. See my answer here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55889947/how-to-pan-a-javafx-linechart?noredirect=1#comment98438034_55889947

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the series:

```
XYChart.Series<Number, Number> s = lineChart.getData().get(0);
```

Shift the time frame/range by removing first element and adding new one:

```
s.getData().remove(0);
s.getData().add(new LineChart.Data<Number,Number>(time_from_server, data_from_server));
```