# How to pan a JavaFX LineChart

Tags: javafx, linechart

In JavaFx I have a LineChart `lc` for which I create and add a series,

```
lc.getData().addAll(series1);
```

It displays just fine, but seems to sample *all* data points to fit the whole domain into the chart.

Is there a way to force the LineChart to just display the last 10 data points, say, of the series?

Ultimately I would like to create a way to *pan* the chart contents so that a window of the data is displayed, as a function of pan position.

I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064727/how-to-update-javafx-linechart-data) but it removes data, which means I would then need to add it back. I would rather keep all data in the series if possible, and set the usable range of that series if possible.

Comment: that's not supported by core fx - maybe the fx extension to jfreechart does?

Comment: @kleopatra I found a solution using core fx... please see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I worked out the solution myself using the standard fx libraries.

So long as the horizontal axis is a `NumberAxis`, you can use the `setLowerBound()` and `setUpperBound()` functions.

Combined with a scrollbar this works perfectly.

For example,

```
    final static int MAX_DISPLAY = 100
    LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart;
    ScrollBar scroller;

    scroller.setMin(0);
    scroller.setMax(1000 - MAX_DISPLAY);

    scroller.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number number, Number t1) {

            double pos = scroller.getValue();

            NumberAxis na = (NumberAxis)lineChart.getXAxis();
            na.setLowerBound(pos);
            na.setUpperBound(pos + MAX_DISPLAY);
        }
    });
```

Note - if using Scene Builder, your LineChart x-axis will default to CatergoryAxis, so make sure to edit the .fxml file and change it to NumberAxis manually.

Additionally, for my use case since the x-axis represents Unix epoch times, you can convert the `Number` values into something else using the following code (in my case a date formatted string),

```
        NumberAxis xAxis = (NumberAxis)lineChart.getXAxis();

        xAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new StringConverter<Number>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(Number object) {

                return convertToDate(object.longValue());
            }

            @Override
            public Number fromString(String string) {
                return 0;
            }
        });
```